# How to increase the weight of observation in boosting regression

Tags: gradient, xgboost, adaboost, boosting

How to increase the weight of observation in boosting regression, like for boosting classification, you could add more weights to the observations who predict wrong but for boosting regression, how could you know which observation is wrong and add weights towards them? Do we have an error range for boosting regression or so?

Answer (score 0):

This is what https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostRegressor.html do.
Refer: Improving Regressors using Boosting Techniques.

Actually, Every step of boosting you have a loss, for example loss=(y-f(x))**2, then you can use loss to represent weight. Weight can be used to two ways. One is using weight to resample dataset. The other is using weight directly in loss, in optimization